# How To Convert Unicode Characters to the correct Language Characters in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, locale, netbeans-7

I have one field in Database with varchar field in which i am storing Thai Sentence (in the form of Unicode ).

What i need is to parse the Unicode characters into the proper String which correctly show thai characters .

My code for displaying thai Characters with the help of Locale object 
using
[Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/examples/ThaiDigits.java)!
is as follows.

```
  Locale thaiLocale_ =  new Locale("th", "TH", "TH");
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(thaiLocale_);
  double theDig_Doub =573.34
  String outputString = new String();
  outputString =nf.format(theDig_Doub);
```

i need the code for Showing sequence of Thai characters.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  First you are talking about parsing Unicode into double, then the code shown is a conversion of double to string according to a certain locale.  Which is the correct one?

Comment: I require both first to convert the unicode Sequence into float and then to display these float reprisentation of the unicode by using the above code , so my

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me ,for displaying Thai Language in NetBeans.

```
     String strThai ="";
    if (rs.getString(i) != null )
        strThai= new String(rs.getString(i).getBytes("ISO8859_1"),"TIS-620");
```

where rs is the ResultSet from the Data Base.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to make sure that the string you are getting from the database is correctly being represented in unicode thai characters.

Because it is possible that the DB storage / retrieval mechanism may have corrupted your thai string.

After you have made sure that the thi characters you are getting from the DB are in the correct form, you can simply use the following code to parse the characters back to as a float.

```
NumberFormat thai = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("th", "TH", "TH"));

String thaiText = db.getValue();// You need to put your db fetching logic here
double number = thai.parse(thaiText).doubleValue();
```

But before all this, make sure the thai characters are coming in correctly back from the DB.

Comment: It means we read character by character from the db not the whole sequence of All characters stored in the varchar field of my db.

Comment: No. You should read the whole string from the DB, not character by character, because character by character might add up to corrupting your string. The main logic behind this comment is, that the thai characters need a 16 bit representation. While the DB storage / fetching mechanism might end up considering your string as a 8 bit represented string. Or might mess up the little-endian / big-endian  structure of your string. So you need to make sure your string is correctly being stored and read.

Comment: Yaar i think the below is the same post  but it is generating following excption java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "ä¢è»ÅÒËÅèÍ" at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:350) at DB.DBEngine.GetResultSet(DBEngine.java:335)

Comment: Shariq bhai i am applying the Code on live Data and we are using it for our program in delphi and it is displaying thai correctors correctly

Comment: The data is stored correctly in the sql server db and also retireved properly in our delphi program as i showed u the screen shot.

Comment: If the data is being fetched correctly, try use the code i mentioned in the answer. See if it works.

Comment: Actually i already applied the code u mentioned but still the saMe exception is coming.Please tell me any algorithm to read the data correctly in sixteen bit as u mentioned earlier that this effect is may be due to the incorrect reading of thai characters from DB. I changed the encoding from UTS-8 to UTS-16, but no effect.

Comment: Is there any way to read the unicode from DB as bits and then print those in the collection of 16   bits sequence.

Comment: If there is a way in your DB layer to read a value as a byte array. You can use this code to convert it to a String using a UTF-16 scheme. String str2 = new String(str.getBytes(), "UTF-16");

Answer (score 0):

You already have the code to convert a double to string via a particular locale.  You can achieve the opposite (converting a string to double) by calling the `parse()` function on the `NumberFormat` object:

```
double num = nf.parse(outputString).doubleValue();
```

You need to call `doubleValue()` on the result of `parse()` as it returns a `Number`, not a `double` directly.

You will need to be prepared to catch a `ParseException` (`java.text.ParseException`) when calling `parse()` as the string passed in might not be a valid number (at least as far as `parse` knows).

The above code uses the `outputString` variable declared in the code in the question.

Comment: the code is generating following excption    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "ä¢è»ÅÒËÅèÍ"
at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:350)
at DB.DBEngine.GetResultSet(DBEngine.java:335)
at

Comment: Even if i parse a single character it generates error               java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "ä"

Comment: I was not at my computer.  That string is not a number, so of course it is throwing an exception.  What value is that in the DB?

Comment: the DB contains the unicode values in varchar field .I am reading that value character by character as you see "ä" .

Comment: I understand the the DB has a varchar field (which translates to a stringin java), but in order to convert it to a number, it needs to be encoding a number.  The string you refer to in your comments above does not encode a number (AFAIK), hence the exception.  What number did you expect to get it converted to, btw?  A valid string that encodes a number is the contents of `outputString` in the code in your question.  If you convert that to a number, there will be no exceptions.  You need to have a similarly formatted string from the DB to be able to convert it to a number.

Comment: Would u please tell that how to format in that string format which u are telling as i am stuck here. I also provide u points if it works for me by accepting your answer. Thanks for prolonged help.

Comment: By the way i am using these formattings                        Locale thaiLocale_ =  new Locale("th", "TH", "TH");        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(thaiLocale_);

Comment: I'm not too familiar with locales, but AFAIK it affects for example how the decimal separator is displayed. The number 9-and-half is displayed as "9.5" in US locale and "9,5" in Hungarian locale. I'm not familiar with the Thai locale (the example produced "?.?" on my console), but using the Hungarian example you would need to pass "9,5" to `parse` with a Hu locale to get the number 9-and-half. At the minimum, I would expect to see a decimal separator in the string from the DB (unless whole number). Can you "translate" the value coming from the DB (the one throwing exception) to English?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Unifun {


    public static String convertunitostring(String s) {

        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(convertunitostring("\ufeff\u0110\u1eaf\u0063\u0020\u004c\u1eaf\u0063"));
    }

}
```

Note:add Apache commons lang jar in class path.